# Reading .evt/.evtx files directly

Tags: c++, windows, event-log, splunk

Hello does anybody know how to read .evt /.evtx which are Windows Event log files to read not using provided api's , I want to read them using `FILE I/O` apis in `C/C++`.

Or how to convert those files into `.txt` , I know `splunk` does this but not sure how they are doing this.

Answer (score 9):

I might be late but well, it could help a future reader so :

To read an **.evt** file with standard lib (let's say in C++), you should be aware of [ELF_LOGFILE_HEADER structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309024(v=vs.85).aspx) and [EVENTLOGRECORD structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363646(v=vs.85).aspx). In addition, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb309026(v=vs.85).aspx) is the event log file format.

Now everything is simpler, what you have to do is :

### I. Declare structures

1. Log Header structure

   ```
   typedef unsigned long ULONG;
   typedef struct _EVENTLOGHEADER {
     ULONG HeaderSize;
     ULONG Signature;
     ULONG MajorVersion;
     ULONG MinorVersion;
     ULONG StartOffset;
     ULONG EndOffset;
     ULONG CurrentRecordNumber;
     ULONG OldestRecordNumber;
     ULONG MaxSize;
     ULONG Flags;
     ULONG Retention;
     ULONG EndHeaderSize;
   } EVENTLOGHEADER, *PEVENTLOGHEADER;
   ```
2. Log Record structure

   ```
   typedef unsigned long DWORD;
   typedef unsigned short WORD;
   typedef struct _EVENTLOGRECORD {
       DWORD Length;
       DWORD Reserved;
       DWORD RecordNumber;
       DWORD TimeGenerated;
       DWORD TimeWritten;
       DWORD EventID;
       WORD  EventType;
       WORD  NumStrings;
       WORD  EventCategory;
       WORD  ReservedFlags;
       DWORD ClosingRecordNumber;
       DWORD StringOffset;
       DWORD UserSidLength;
       DWORD UserSidOffset;
       DWORD DataLength;
       DWORD DataOffset;
   } EVENTLOGRECORD, *PEVENTLOGRECORD;
   ```

### II Let's read !

First declare a `std::ifstream` variable to open and read the file (binary)

```
using namespace std;
ifstream file;
file.open(fileName,ios::in|ios::binary);

if(file.is_open()){
    _EVENTLOGHEADER logheader;
    _EVENTLOGRECORD logRecord;

    //Reading the header
    file.read((char*)&logheader,sizeof(_EVENTLOGHEADER));

    int startOfLog;
    //Loop on every record
    for(unsigned int numberFile=0;numberFile < logheader.CurrentRecordNumber -1;numberFile++){
        //Save the position
        startOfLog = file.tellg();
        //Read log record
        file.read((char*)&logRecord,sizeof(_EVENTLOGRECORD));

        /*******************************************************
        Here are the other information (section 'Remarks' on the 'EVENTLOGRECORD structure' link 
        ********************************************************/

        //Reading sourcename
        wchar_t buffData;
        wstring SourceName;
        file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
        while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
            SourceName.push_back(buffData);
            file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
        }

        //Reading computer name
        wstring ComputerName;
        file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
        while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
            ComputerName.push_back(buffData);
            file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
        }

        //Sets the position to the SID offset 
        int readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.UserSidOffset;
        file.seekg(readCursor);

        char * userSid = NULL;
        if(logRecord.UserSidLength != 0)
        {
            userSid = (PCHAR)malloc(logRecord.UserSidLength);
            file.read(userSid,logRecord.UserSidLength); //Reading the sid
            //Here you can work on the SiD (but you need win32 API).If you need it, I could show you how i deal with this sid 
            free(userSid);
        }

        //Sets the position to the Strings offset
        readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.StringOffset;
        file.seekg(readCursor);
        wstring buffString;
        vector<wstring> allStrings;
        //Reading all the strings
        for(int i=0; i< logRecord.NumStrings; i++) {
            file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            while(buffData!=_T('\0')){
                buffString.push_back(buffData);
                file.read((char*)&buffData,sizeof(wchar_t));
            }
            allStrings.push_back(buffString);
            buffString.clear();
        }

        //Sets the position to the Data offset
        readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.DataOffset;
        file.seekg(readCursor);
        unsigned char *Data = (unsigned char *)malloc(logRecord.DataLength*sizeof(unsigned char));
        file.read((char*)Data,logRecord.DataLength); //Lecture des données

        //Sets the position to the end of log offset
        readCursor = startOfLog + logRecord.Length - sizeof(DWORD) ;
        file.seekg(readCursor);
        DWORD length;
        file.read((char*)&length,sizeof(DWORD));

        //Do what you want with the log record

        //Clean before reading next log
        ComputerName.clear();
        SourceName.clear();
        allStrings.clear();
        free(Data);
    }
}
```

Wish it could help someone,

Comment: That's nice. And regarding SID would like to have it as a string. But all i could read was some garbage value into my char* usersid. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for this for hours.

Comment: I have started working this , thanks @Bastien its too late:)