# Reading a saved EVTX file in the given path

Tags: c++, c, winapi, event-log

I am currently working on a project where I need to read windows events .
I am using OpenEventLog() and ReadEventLog() from Win API. I can read the events from system using the typename of the event.
But I need to specify the file name or file path of the .evtx file that I have saved from the EventViewer.I tried the below code,

```
HANDLE logHandle = OpenEventLog(NULL, "C:\\Users\\MyAccount\\Documents\\myevents.evtx");
DWORD status = GetLastError();
if(logHandle == NULL){
    cerr<<"NO HANDLE GENERATED!!!"<<endl;
}else if(status == ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE){
    cerr<<"INVALID HANDLE!!!"<<endl;
}else if(status!=0){
    cout<<"OPENEVENTLOG ERROR STATUS::>"<<status<<endl;
}
```

But it does not find the specified file and switches over to default Application Events. Can anyone please tell me what the problem could be? or if there is anything to be changed in the code?

PS: I even tried placing the file in project folder and specifying just the filename(myevents.evtx) , but still doesn't work.I also tried reading the evtx directly as shown in ["Reading .evt/.evtx files directly"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16730103/9288733) , but later I found this can't be done. Apparently there is no way to read them directly without win API or without writing a whole bunch of parser code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the status (last error) that you've got?

Comment: It was 0. It didn't report any other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out `OpenEventLog()` is not meant for opening saved `.evtx` files.
I should've been using `OpenBackupEventLog()` for that.